# FCM Message body truncated when sending from Server side

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I just would like to send notification message using FCM.
And then building server side to send notification using XMPP protocol 
not using Firebase SDK. 
Then I found the notification body is truncated like this image.

[image]

This image is just copied and pasted from this github link:
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/108

How to expand the body message? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi PM11. It would be helpful if you could post your code so far.

Answer (score 2):

Change your notification like this

```
    builder.setContentText(message);
    builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message));
```

Then it shouldn't truncate

Answer (score 0):

The full notification body is being received.  You need to take an action to expand the notification display.  This varies some with phone model and API level.  If there is no down-arrow for expand, touch the notification with two fingers and pull down.  The notification will expand to show all the received text.